# error 502.5 and System.IO.FileNotFoundException

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, http, iis, system.io.file

When I try to navigate to my domain name that I set up with IIS (it's a ASP.NET Core app) I get the error:

> HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure

I then try to run it via the cmd to get a more elaborate error message:

> C:\inetpub\wwwroot\algoritmtrading.se>mvcrepetition.dll
>
> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Any tips?

Comment: Are you running the IIS service as "ADMIN"?  A user connecting with the web service normally has GUEST privilege and doesn't have the users credentials.

Comment: The idea is that a regular user is supposed to be able to visit my site, and guess they wlll be considered guests. 

Will this change if I run the IIS as admin? thought that I just needed to set it up the website once in IIS and then  be able to start accessing it online from any computer or ip?

Thanks

Comment: They will still be able to be GUEST and have access only to objects that the service uses.  The other choice is to change the privilege of the file.folder to GUEST.

Comment: Thanks for the help, you mean in the security part of properties on the folder right?
Just giver Users full control?

Comment: Yes.  You probably want to Read and Execute, but not necessarily write.

Comment: Did those changes but get the same error message as before. Any other suggestions? 
Thanks

Comment: I think you need to install the application by publishing the application and then running setup.exe  on Server.  I suspect you built app on one PC and now running on another PC.  For a VS app to run on another PC and exact same version of Net Library must be on both PCs.  The setup.exe installs the correct version of dlls on installed PC so app will run.  It looks like the server has Net Library 4.1.  Did you build your project with 4.1?  What platform are you using (Any CPU)?

Comment: You are absolutely correct, I built my app on my laptop and am now trying to run my app on a remote machine (am a real rook so thanks for the patience). 

I looked in the regedit and can see that the versions look different:  
                       https://imgur.com/a/ORX6Y                         
Can't find that setup.exe though, where do I find this on my virtual machine?
Not sure what I used for my project, just been using VS2017 c#.
Thanks

Comment: Under the Build option in VS there is a Publish Option.   Select Publish to CD.  You can select any files system instead of CD.  Then you will get a folder like commercial release software where the root folder contains setup.exe. Move the entire folder to a location that is accessible to the server and run like any commercial software release.

Comment: I don't seem to have this setup ni the wwwroot of the published file. 
Have images folder with images and a js folder: https://imgur.com/a/rCJ6j
The rest of the folders and dll files look like this: https://imgur.com/a/wLlLx

Comment: To you have your explore showing System Files?  Make sure nothing is hidden.

Comment: Changed to show all files including system files, still nothing. 
Also searched for *.exe afterwards, nothing comes up. 
https://imgur.com/a/LAnYW

Comment: Publish may require a Release build and you may only have a debug build  Check the project bin folder to see if you have both a release and debug.  Check times of the file to make sure they are current.

Comment: Have both release and debug, the release is the newest one that I've done a couple of times over. No *.exe or setup in the release. 
This is a asp.net app, maybe that matters?

Starting to think there is something wrong in the IIS?

Comment: Is there a dll?  dll are equivalent to exe provided there is a main function.  So maybe there is no main in your project.  Some dlls run by double clicking on dll from a window explorer and some do not.  The difference are the ones that have main().

Comment: Got it to work with some local help, big thanks for your help and patience jdweng, I really appreciate it. 
Maybe my question wasn't superbly asked in regards to the solution below but it's very nice to met awesome people who put effort into helping strangers here on stackoverflow so once again, big thanks jdweng.

Answer (score 0):

Finally managed to get it to work with some local help. 
The solution was to first go to cmd and write "dotnet run"  in the folder where the actual project was located instead of going to the folder where the solution was located. 
Before I was in folder 'MVCkod\MVCrepetition20170721'
Was told to go to 'MVCkod\MVCrepetition20170721\src\MVCrepetition'
That gave the error message Framework 1.1.2 was not found.

Then I downloaded this versin of framework from online and just run the downloaded file. I once again wrote "dotnet run" in folder 'MVCkod\MVCrepetition20170721\src\MVCrepetition' which gave me another error message which is shown in the picture below. That error message was understandable and I've worked it out (now I'm getting the error message 500 when navigating to my domain but that's another problem. 
[folders picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6D3ev.png)