# dll works fine locally but not found after installation

Tags: c#, c++, .net, dll

I use a dll for plate recognition in my project. dll belongs to a third party company and I think made by c++.
These lines use in my project:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "CopyMemory", SetLastError = false)]
            public static extern void CopyMemory(IntPtr dest, IntPtr src, uint count);

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport( "ANPR.dll",CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl )]
    unsafe public static extern short anpr_create(byte instance, char* security_code, byte log_level);  

 ANPR_API.anpr_create(0, p, 0);
```

The problem is when I run my project in debug or release mode everything works fine but when create .exe file and install on client machine or even on my computer, nothings happen!
`anpr.dll` is on the same folder beside .exe file but seems to be not found by application.
 I try to copy the dll in `systemwow64`, `system32`, but the same problem still exists.
Also dll is not for adding to reference or register with `regsvr32`.

can anybody help me please?

p.s: I created my .exe file with with `Advanced Installer` and also with `VS.2015` publish command.

Comment: Did you try publish application and then install using setup.exe folder.  You may neeed to download the dotnet utilty from msdn.  See answer at following posting : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48344913/error-502-5-and-system-io-filenotfoundexception#comment83799298_48344913

Comment: Have you installed `Visual C++ Redist` x86 or x64 on the target marchine?

Comment: @AliBahraminezhad Yes, I downloaded the latest version and install it but still nothing!